# Notice: Undefined index while uploading photo

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a image but i am unable to do it. Whenever i upload a image it says an undefined index. It says 'photo' is an undefined index. 
here is my form code.

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" required>
```

and my php code

```
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $photo = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; //error occured on this line

    $add_photo = "insert into photo values(NULL, 1, '$photo')";
    $res1 = querySelect($add_photo);

    $target = "../../images/".basename($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    echo $target;
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    } else {
        echo "Successfull";
    };

    //header("location: ../view/home.php");
}
```

All the field is inserted to the database but the only the problem is photo doesn't move to the given directory.

[And my folder descriptin is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSbVB.png)

And sorry for poor english

Comment: how you are using   $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']?  instead of  $_FILES['photo']?

Comment: check for the file with `if($_FILES['photo']['name'] != "")`

Comment: The file might be too big. What is the file size and what is the max post & filesize in php.ini.  If it's too big, php doesn't allow the file to upload with as result, no tmp name.

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form`?

Comment: Yes i have added